# How do i get the bullets to emit directly forwards, ignoring the physics of the player (rolling)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The issue with my code is that the bullets will basically spill out of the player object but i cannot get them to shoot directly forward to hit the obstacles. 
Instead, as the player rolls each direction, the bullets come out the same set vector which is not what i want. I'd like the bullets to shoot along the x-axis only while instead, they shoot out of all sides depending on how the player rolls.

I've tried changing the bullet rotation and force, in the case that the bullet force altered the player direction and momentum. That failed so i removed the players forward force to test, and still no progress.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float backwardForce = -60f;
    public float forwardForce = 100f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 1f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 100, 200);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Movement force
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 50.0f * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Force);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(backwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Force);
        }


        /*switch (Input.GetKeyDown())
         {

            // case Input.GetKeyDown("a"):


            //a: rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class BulletShoot : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Reference to bullet emitter
    public GameObject Bullet_Emitter;

    //Reference to bullet prefab
    public GameObject Bullet;

    //Forward force of bullet
    public float Bullet_Force;// = 10.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //When "Space" key is pressed..
        if (Input.GetKey("space")){

            //Temp variable that will hold reference to bullet
            GameObject tempBulletHandler;

            //Temp then instantiates bullet to game using emitter position and angle
            tempBulletHandler = Instantiate(Bullet, Bullet_Emitter.transform.position, Bullet_Emitter.transform.rotation);

            //Corrects angle that bullets appear
            tempBulletHandler.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * 180);

            //RigidBody instantiated to control bullet physics using bullet handler
            Rigidbody tempRigidBody = tempBulletHandler.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            //Add force to the rigidbody to simulate firing the bullet forward using set bullet force
            tempRigidBody.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Bullet_Force);

            //Free up space from bullets fired (after 4 sec)
            Destroy(tempBulletHandler, 4.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected: Player moves forward continuously while having the ability to shoot obstacles in a linear direction.

Actual: Player moves correctly but bullets emit with no control, like rice falling out of a bag with one hole that keeps spinning in all directions.

Comment: If your bullets are parented to something that moves, the bullets will move with it.  You almost certainly want to remove the parent to make them indepentant

Comment: Ok... But the parent is the player so how would it work if there's no source to shoot from?

Comment: But once shot they arent dependant on the player any more, they need to be their own thing, heading in their own directions.. think like space invaders, if you fire and move to the right you dont want your bullet moving to the right with you..  Same thing..  You spawn it, but then unparent it so it can live its own life

Comment: Hey really sorry, how do i make it so that you've answered the question? Your explanations helped me better understand my issue so now i know how to fix it, but haven't gotten around to it. been busy..

Comment: Lemme put what I said in an answer, then you can tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common early issue, when you instantiate something like bullets, arrows, even particles from something if you do instantiate(myprefab, transform) whatever the transform was you assigned is now the objects parent. So, if that instantiate was a box for the player to carry, that can be fine, because as the parent/player moves the box will move too, great.  Dont need to code that.

Imagine space invaiders, if you fired on the left up at a nasty, and then wanted to head to the far right, what you expect is that missile you sent up to stay going up, in that column to the nasty, what would currently happen is your missile as you moved to the right, also moves to the right. You need to unparent the missle so it can now move its merry way on and be free to move in the direction you set it off in.

In short, you would then set missle.transform.SetParent(newParent); where newparent can even be null, which places it at the top level of the hierarchy.

Comment: So that's the trick use in Wanted, the movie. When filming the bullet the shooter has to move outside of the screen to make the bullet move.

Comment: Cant say I saw the film, but, its easy to replicate if you take like a capsule, and instantiate a box and run around the box comes with, even if you apply force on pressing a button say as you move the box will come and move with you

Comment: harg my English is so bad I can't even make a joke. Yes it's a know "feature" when instantiate things. That people always discover when using projectiles and particles. As they create a curving effect they can almost control by moving the emiter. The joke was : "If it works that way on Unity, then its possible that it work in reallity too, as in the movie they were able to curve the bullet. Possibly by throwing the actor around at hight speed.". -- Your explanation are clear

Comment: Sorry @xdtTransform that I didnt get your joke.  it would be cool though wouldnt it if it was real

Comment: OK, so i'm still pretty new to this. If my player object is a sphere, do i have to release the emitter from the player also? If so, how would i position it in front of the player if the player? Also, would i order the release of the bullet within the if or separate with the emitter?

Comment: @ElishuaBrown that would be a new question, you should ask it as such, especially as this is months old